How to bypass localhost mapping through web pack
I have the following scenario: I have the domain name setup as mysite-recon.xyz.
I have the /etc/host file setup which maps the above URL to localhost:8030. All the react JS bundle files are fetched from the localhost like
http://mysite-recon.xyz:8030/app.js
But I want to use the same URL for file upload which looks like mysite-recon.xyz/u/o/hash but I want to use the actual service but because it is mapped to localhost I am unable to upload the file. Is there any way in webpack I can do this.
I have tried webpack proxy config which looks like this but of no help
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true,
  allowedHosts: 'all',
  https: true,
  hot: true,
  proxy: {
    '/u/o': {
      agent: new HttpsProxyAgent('http://mysite-recon.xyz:8030'),
      target: 'https://mysite-recon.xyz',
      pathRewrite: { '^/u/o': '' },
      changeOrigin: true,
    },
  },
}

